# Prestashop Sell Option - Preowned Items

Tags: prestashop

I'm completely new to Prestashop.

I have selected Prestashop as my platform for creating my intended shopping site. But I'd like to add one option "Sell" beside "Buy" button.

On clicking the "Sell" button it'll take me to a page, where the user needs to fill up a form, which will designed by me ofcourse with few textbox and dropdowns, And once he goes through the process, the data's will be saved in database.

Now in PHP, I can write this code within minutes, but I don't know and have no idea how to integrate this thing in prestashop.

So if anyone here can please help me out, I'll be glad.

Allow me to let you know, that I want this "Sell" idea on my shopping site, where generally people comes to Buy, is because I want to enable my site for 2nd Hand items, i.e. refurbished items. So I need an option to buy refurbished items through which users can sell me their refurbished items.

I don't know whether any plugin is available for this, though I don't see any normally through basic searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to develop your own module, which will show the "Sell" button using a hook in Prestashop template file(s), and create a new resource (your page with form) in your shop. Check Prestashop documentation and tutorials, [Creating a Prestashop module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module) and adding custom hooks in tpl files can be found at [Creating custom hooks ...](http://blog.premium-templates.eu/creating-custom-hooks-in-prestashop-1-5-the-easy-way) blog.